# How to auto link classes when compiling c++ in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation, libcurl

I am writing software in eclipse and i am using libcurl. In order for me to compile it, i have to go to the terminal(ubuntu) and after cd-ing to the directory wiht the .cpp file, i have to run this:

```
g++ -g -Wall -o myapp myapp.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl
```

How do I configure the eclipse compiler to run this when comiling for me, instead of me having to run the terminal everytime.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

project -> properties -> c/c++ build -> settings -> gcc c++ linker -> libraries

click on green + icon
add your library name (without -l)

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a tool chain and and add a make file target. 
You can try to create a new Hello World project (file--> New --> C++ project --> Hello World C++-Project ) and add after that adapt to your needs (do renaming, add your classes)...
After creating the project it should be visible in the Project explorer. Open the Makefile and set

- CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -L/usr/local/lib
- LIBS     = -lcurl
- TARGET   = myapp
- OBJS     = myapp.o

Open the Make Target View (Window-->Show View --> Make Target) and add a target to build your all target of the Makefile. You may do this by:

1. In the Make Target View open the context menu by clicking right on your created/listed project.
2. Choose New...
3. Enter **all** as target name
4. Click (double click) on **all** to start the build process
5. Check the console output

Hope this may help